# Is there a way to change variable assignment names

Tags: r

Using R. Is there a way that I can give R any text string and it will treat it like a formula?

An example says it all.

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
d <- 4
```

What if I had to do this all the way up to z?

In R we can write:

```
letters[1]
```

This gives us an "a"

So what about something like this:
(It doesn't work but I'd like to do something like this)

```
for (i in 1:4) {    
  letters[i] <- i
}
```

There's the `as.formula` function but that's only good for formulas like `a ~ b + c`.

Thanks.

Comment: what about `assign(letters[i], i)`

Comment: Yeah, @Alex is right... for the exact problem presented, `sapply(letters, function(x) assign(x, match(x, letters), envir=.GlobalEnv))` would work. Many ways to skin a cat... could also do `list2env(setNames(as.list(1:26), letters), .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Or `list2env(as.list(setNames(1:26, letters)). globalenv())`

Comment: It's usually bad practice to assign variables programmatically like this... Instead, use a list: `vars <- list(); for (i in 1:4) {vars[letters[i]] <- i}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to evaluate a text :

```
eval(parse(text="a<-1"))
```

But if you want to initialize many variables, you can create a named list and convert it to a separate variables (attach each components to the global environment) using `list2env`, but **I would highly recommend  that you keep your variables in the same list**.

```
 xx <- letters[1:5]
 list2env(setNames(seq_along(xx), xx), .GlobalEnv)
```